# When does the board accept an ultimatum?

Tags: football-manager-2008

In some games I have won every title for consecutive seasons with the same club. I ask for something (like stadium upgrade) where the directors are not totally against it (i.e. they have it in mind but are waiting for money or something like that, even when club is rich). When I send the ultimatum (accept request or I leave), they let me leave, despite being the manager with the most titles and ranked number 1 in world.

Is there anyway an ultimatum is ever accepted? Or is just a feature of the game unused/bug?

Comment: I would guess it may also depend on the chairman/board/club.  I have used ultimatum in the past and kept my job (can't say this specifically in FM2008).  I also doubt you could use ultimatum for something the club cannot do (e.g. don't have enough money).

Comment: The problem is that the club did have money, like, tons of money. And I only played FM2008 so can't say anything about others FM.

Comment: Perhaps the stadium expansion is not possible because the current stadium is at maximum capacity.  There are a lot of attributes (would have to check editors to say for sure) that come in to play on such decisions.